# is it possible to create JAR version with semver + custom number like1.2.3.myrelease.release1?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, dependencies

is it possible to create JAR version with semver + custom number like1.2.3.myrelease.release1?

And then create a dependency and publish it into maven repository to let developers add into maven/gradle build file with this version?

**UPD:** actually the question is: what kind of trouble could be met with this customizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version can be any String.

The question is whether this is a good idea. It is usually better to follow the standards of the community.

Comment: you're right, actually the question is: what kind of trouble could be met with this customizing?